# How to write union query in spring data jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am facing some challenge while writing the union query in spring data jpa.
below is my query

```
select 
  u.* 
from 
  public.users u, 
  user_groups ug, 
  group og 
where 
  u.id = ug.user_id 
  and ug.org_group_id = og.id 
  and u.status in ('ISSUED') 
  and og.id in (: groupId) 
union 
select 
  u.* 
from 
  public.users u, 
  ugroups ug, 
  groups og, 
  history ueh 
where 
  ueh.user_id = u.id 
  and u.id = ug.user_id 
  and ug.org_group_id = og.id 
  and ueh.status in (
    'APPROVED', 
    'REJECTED'
  ) 
  and og.id in (: groupId)
```

The above query I am writing in the repository class using nativeQuery=true.
from my serviceImpl class, I am calling this method and passing the pagable object for the pagination.

Here the problem is that in pagable I am also passing the sort value, which is name, and it is there in the users table.

```
                        sortBy = "name";
                        sort = Sort.by(direction, sortBy);
```

but the final query appended as

```
order by u.name ASC;
```

because of this, u.name getting the following error

missing from-clause entry for table "u".

can anybody please help to resolve this issue.